# How Can I solve my "Objects are not valid as a React child" issue?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've build the following [example](https://jsbin.com/citehi/11/edit?html,console,output) to learn about react/redux. Here is the reducer I have :

```
const tableFilter = (state = 0, action) => {
    if(action.type === 'SET_TABLE_DATA') {
        return state + 1;
    }
        return state;
  }
```

At that point everything works fine. However I'm trying to follow this tutorial [APPLYING REDUX REDUCERS TO ARRAYS](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/05/19/redux-reducer-arrays.html) and when updating my reducer with the following code :

```
//========Reducer===================
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  value: 0,
  warning: false
}
const update = (state, mutations) => Object.assign({}, state, mutations)
const tableFilter = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  if(action.type === 'SET_TABLE_DATA') {
    return state = update(state, { value: state.value + 1 })
  }
  return state;
}
const FilterApp = combineReducers({tableFilter});
//==================================

const DisplayTable = ({test, DisplayTable}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={DisplayTable}>{test}</button>
      <p></p>
    </div> 
  )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      test: state.tableFilter
  };
};

const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    DisplayTable: () => {
      dispatch (setTableFilter());
    }
  };
};

const AppTable = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(DisplayTable);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(FilterApp)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

I've got this error  `...Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value, warning})....`

Looking at others questions here it seems to be a recurrent issue, however the solution is always different. What does this error message really mean ? how can I solve it in my case ? Is there something I need to modify in my component ?

here is my [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pineyec/1/edit?html,console,output) with the updated reducer.

thanks

Comment: I don't see a component in the code you've posted.  You've posted a Redux reducer.  That error is coming from React and is likely due to your `render` method returning objects that aren't React components.

Comment: Hey Brandon. Thanks. I've updated my post to make it more clear. tell me if that's ok now ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to render an object directly in JSX and that just isn't allowed.

```
<button onClick={DisplayTable}>{test}</button>
```

Here test is an object, not a valid React child.
Try

```
<button onClick={DisplayTable}>{String(test.warning)} {test.value}</button>
```

Updated [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/cozopipeto/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: @SimonBreton just updated your JSBin and it works just fine there. Where did you even get the setState function?

Comment: Ok it's working. Thanks a lot :) So you mean that by modifying my reducer I'm now rendering an object ?

Comment: Actually it was only because of the `warning: false` and that's why you told me to add the string stuff. If I took of this warning thing everything work just fine with `{test.value}` Thanks.